# ggplot2: center legend below plot instead of panel area

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

`ggplot` by default centers the legend below the panel, which is really frustrating in some situations. Please see the below example:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(cut, fill = clarity)) + geom_bar() + coord_flip() + 
  theme(legend.position = 'bottom')
```

[image]

It can be seen that the last label was cropped from the image, although we have some white-space on the left part of the legend -- it would be a lot better to use that.

**Q**: how can I center the legend below the plot and not try to force that to be centered below the panel area to overcome this issue?

---

**Update**: further example on this issue:

```
df <- data.frame(
    x = sample(paste('An extremely long category label that screws up legend placement', letters[1:7]), 1e3, TRUE),
    y = sample(paste('Short label', letters[1:7]), 1e3, TRUE)
    )

ggplot(df, aes(x, fill = y)) + geom_bar() + coord_flip() +
  theme(legend.position = 'bottom')
```

[image]

---

**What I've done:** I can use `legend.direction` to manually put the legend below the panel and to add some extra margin below the plot, like:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(cut, fill = clarity)) + geom_bar() + coord_flip() + 
  theme(legend.position  = c(0.37, -0.1),
        legend.direction = 'horizontal',
        plot.margin      = grid::unit(c(0.1,0.1,2,0.1), 'lines'))
```

[image]

But this way I have to compute "manually" the optimal `legend.position`. Any suggestions?

---

**Update**: I am arranging multiple plots next to each other, so I'd rather not center the legend on the actual image, but rather on the single panel. E.g.:

```
p1 <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(cut)) + geom_histogram()
p2 <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(cut, fill = clarity)) + geom_bar() + coord_flip() +
  theme(legend.position = 'bottom')
pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(nrow = 1, ncol = 2, widths = unit(c(1, 2), c("null", "null")))))
print(p1, vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = 1, layout.pos.col = 1))
print(p2, vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = 1, layout.pos.col = 2))
```

Comment: Rather than moving the text, couldn't you increase the right margin so it doesn't cut off your text? ```plot.margin = grid::unit(c(0.1,10,2,0.1), 'lines')``` The original plot renders fine in my window, so I can't see if this works.

Comment: @Reed thanks, but I cannot. Even more: this problem is due to the fact that the width of the plot is limited. Imagine if the categories of `cut` are a lot longer. I'll try to come up with some more relevant examples.

Answer (score 7):

I was looking for a solution to this problem and realized that I can use [Claus Wilke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4975218/claus-wilke)'s [cowplot](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/vignettes/introduction.html) to split the plot into a grid. This is a bit of a hack but quite easy.

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = sample(paste('An extremely long category label that screws up legend placement', letters[1:7]), 1e3, TRUE),
  y = sample(paste('Short label', letters[1:7]), 1e3, TRUE)
)
```

First let's save the original plot to an object:

```
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x, fill = y)) + geom_bar() + coord_flip() +
  theme(legend.position = 'bottom')
```

Next we'll save another version of it without the legend and use cowplot's `get_legend()` to save the legend:

```
p2 <- p1 + theme(legend.position = "none")
le1 <- cowplot::get_legend(p1)
```

Draw the plot.

```
cowplot::plot_grid(p2, le1, nrow = 2, rel_heights = c(1, 0.2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

you can edit the gtable,

```
library(gtable)

g <- ggplotGrob(p)
id <- which(g$layout$name == "guide-box")
g$layout[id, c("l","r")] <- c(1, ncol(g))
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```

Comment: Awesome (+1), thank you @baptiste. I'll still wait for some other alternative solutions for a few extra days before accepting your answer, as I am currently arranging multiple plots next to each other (pls see the updated question), so I do not want to center the legend on the graphics device, but on the plot area.